# Dates side by side in Sitecore content editor

Tags: content-editor, speak, datetimepicker

There is a Date field in Sitecore. Can we put two dates side by side in Sitcore content editor like this

[image: side by side]

Is this possible to do it in the content editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore doesn't have such a functionality OOTB .
You can have 2 different DateTime fields and you can add them in a single section of the template or you can build your own custom field to look exactly on your screenshot.

I prefer the first variant because the second one with custom field needs to be upgraded for the future upgraded of the platform.

Comment: adding them in a single section, the dates will still be in different line. They won't be side by side

Comment: yep will not be side by side, the editors needs to be educated to use the platform as it is. Such  a change will not bring big value to their project.

Answer (score -1):

The side-by-side date is not available OOTB in `Sitecore`. you can create a custom field for this requirement where you can design your side-by-side date field.

Here is the link to create a custom field:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/web-forms-for-marketers/en/create-a-custom-field-type.html